# Error Converting JSON Value to type `System.Collections.Generic.List` using Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I have to make a `put` request to a web api with `json` information that I get from a QR Code... But I get an error when converting the `json` object to a `InscripcionesModel` at this line:

```
var DatosRegistro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<InscripcionesModel>>(jsonInscripcion);
```

Here is a screenshot of the JSON object (I have validated it):
[image: JSON object causing the error]

This is the method that I used for reading the QR Code to convert the json to a `InscripcionesModel` object:

```
private async void QRButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();
                scanner.TopText = "Acerque la camara al codigo QR del cliente";
                scanner.BottomText = "SataTech";
                var result = await scanner.Scan();
                
                
                if (result != null)
                {
                   
                    //Inscripcion
                    var text = Encriptacion.Decrypt(result.ToString());
                    Uri RequestUri = new Uri(Link);
                    var Inscripciones = new HttpClient();
                    var jsonInscripcion = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(text);
                    var contentJsonInscripcion = new StringContent(jsonInscripcion, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                    //Registro                
                    var DatosRegistro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<InscripcionesModel>>(jsonInscripcion);
                    await DisplayAlert("Mensaje", DatosRegistro[0].DNI, "OK");
                    RegistrosModel registro = new RegistrosModel
                    {
                        Fecha_hora = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"),
                        Dni = DatosRegistro[0].DNI,
                        Id_inscripcion = DatosRegistro[0].Id_inscripcion,
                        Id_disciplina = DatosRegistro[0].Id_disciplina

                    };
                    //Peticion Inscripcion
                    var respoonseInscripcion = await Inscripciones.PutAsync(urlInscripcion + DatosRegistro[0].Id_inscripcion.ToString(), contentJsonInscripcion);

                    //Peticion Registro
                    Uri RequestUriRegistros = new Uri(Link);
                    var Registros = new HttpClient();
                    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(registro);
                    var contentJson = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    var response = await Registros.PostAsync(RequestUriRegistros, contentJson);
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("Mensaje", "Muy felices de tenerte de vuelta!\nA entrenar!", "OK");
                       
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("Mensaje", "Acerquese a recepcion!\nDisculpe las molestias!", "OK");
                    }
                    base.OnAppearing();
                }
                
                


            }
            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", exception.Message.ToString(), "Ok");
            }
}
```

And here is the `InscripcionesModel`:

```
class InscripcionesModel
    {
        public int Id_inscripcion { get; set; }
        public int Id_disciplina { get; set; }
        public int Dias_disponibles { get; set; }
        public string DNI { get; set; }
        public DateTime Fecha_vencimiento { get; set; }
        public int Descuento { get; set; }
        public string Pagado { get; set; }
        public DateTime Fecha_alta { get; set; }
        public string Libre { get; set; }
        public string DiasD { get { return "Dias disponibles: " + Dias_disponibles; } }
    }
```

Comment: You're trying to deserialize JSON to a list, but your JSON just represents a single object.

Comment: var DatosRegistro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InscripcionesModel>(jsonInscripcion); ???

Comment: Quite possibly. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, but now i have a different error: Error converting value to type 'App.Models.InscripcionesModel'

Comment: Okay, so now you've got a different error, and you should probably create a new post to show that, ideally with a [mcve], and definitely with the exact error message, where it occurs etc. (Emphasis on the minimal here - very little of the 61 lines of your first code snippet is actually relevant.)

Comment: Okay! i will! Thank you for being nice!